# Use Handlebars template with express/serve-index

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'd like to serve a folder with express/serve-index within a custom template.

Here is how I try to do it :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const serveIndex = require('serve-index');

app.use('/presentations', express.static('./presentations'), serveIndex('./presentations', {
        icons:true,
        stylesheet:'styles.css',
        view:'details',
        template: (locals,cb) => {
            cb(null,
                app.render('dir',{'title':'Presentations'},(err,html) => {
                    if(err) {console.log(err)};
                    console.log(html);
                    return html;
                })
            )
        }
  }));
```

And as you could expect, here is the error it returns when trying to render this route :

```
buffer.js:481
    throw new TypeError('"string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer');
    ^

    TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
        at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:481:11)
        at send (/home/josselin/git/myRev/node_modules/serve-index/index.js:503:42)
        at /home/josselin/git/myRev/node_modules/serve-index/index.js:211:9
        at template (/home/josselin/git/myRev/index.js:32:9)
        at /home/josselin/git/myRev/node_modules/serve-index/index.js:209:7
        at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

I'm quite sure I shouldn't use `app.render` like that, but I don't really know  how to do it...

Before using the function entrypoint, I tried to use  `app.render` string return directly so it would at least process it and show my logs, and in that case `html` is constructed as it should, but serve-index still renders with its default template.

For reference, here are the versions I use in my requires :

```
"express": "4.16.2",
"express-handlebars": "3.0.0",
"serve-index": "1.9.1"
```